# Is there any way to right align the text in a JCombobox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, renderer, right-align

I want to have a JComboBox with right align. how can I do that?
someone before said "You can set a renderer to the JComboBox which can be a JLabel having JLabel#setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT)" but I don't know how can I do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> someone before said "You can set a renderer to the JComboBox which can be a JLabel having JLabel#setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT)"

Yes, the default renederer is a JLabel so you don't need to create a custom renderer. You can just use:

```
((JLabel)comboBox.getRenderer()).setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
```

Comment: +1, your answer is better than mine, thanks for this information.

Comment: Idk...I think a better answer still would be a combination of your two answers. In particular, your answer is more useful to me because I am using my own custom renderer. On the other hand, I can see how if you are just using a plain array of Strings in the Model (or the toString() for the objects in the combobox is good enough), then it would be more useful to do this.

Answer (score 7):

Well, you can do with ListCellRenderer, like this:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ComboboxDemo extends JFrame{
    public ComboboxDemo(){
        JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>();
        comboBox.setRenderer(new MyListCellRenderer());
        comboBox.addItem("Hi");
        comboBox.addItem("Hello");
        comboBox.addItem("How are you?");

        getContentPane().add(comboBox, "North");
        setSize(400, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private static class MyListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            Component component = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
            component.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
            return component;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ComboboxDemo().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: i cant choose orientation *CENTER* !! only left to right and right to left

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me  nice and short

```
comboFromDuration.setRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                setHorizontalAlignment(DefaultListCellRenderer.CENTER);
                setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                setForeground(Color.GRAY);  
                setEnabled(false);
                super.paint(g);
            }
        });
```

To avoid the setters on every paint(Graphics) call, you could also use an anonymous constructor block:

```
comboFromDuration.setRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
    {
        setHorizontalAlignment(DefaultListCellRenderer.CENTER);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setForeground(Color.GRAY);  
        setEnabled(false);
    }
});
```